The code execution cannot proceed because git-2.0.dll was not found
When on my laptop then I get this error 2 times in a row. Almost it going to 1 month but I couldn't solve yet. And also I can't run c/c++ code as well, but i don't know is it connected with it or not?

Please anyone help me about this error? Please help me to solve this.
